# Why does Ubuntu's installer fail with an error made of question marks?

Tags: system-installation, usb, ubiquity

I bought a Toshiba KIRAbook. It has Windows 8. I tried to install Ubuntu from USB driver 16.04 but it gave an awkward error in the "Preparing to install Ubuntu" step. The error consisted of question marks separated by a space:

> ??? ???

- I tried the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.
- I tried the 16.04 and 17.04 version.
- And I tried to install from "Try Ubuntu" option.

It is not about the USB drive because I has installed on another desktop before a couple weeks ago, and it worked.

Does anyone have any idea?

The error looks like this:

[image: screenshot showing strange error made of question marks]

Comment: It did not work. And I am sure I did true gparted part.I disabled Secured Boot. Do you have any idea what I missed? I don't want to dual boot. Should I delete the other partion at gparted step? Is it go worse?

Comment: I finally did it. I can't make dual-boot.However, I deleted all Windows parts of disk with gparted. And I divided by 3 my Disk, it worked.